# The result this program is wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have written this program and I expect it to print output of '10'. But it is printing 15. Why is it doing this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"iostream"
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void f(int a, int b){
    b=a+a;
}
int main(){
    int a = 5, b = 15;
    f(a,b);
    cout << b;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read about passing by reference and by value. http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html

Comment: You have passed *copies* of those variables, and any changes to those *copies* vanish when their lifetime ends, at function exit.

Answer (score 5):

You pass `a` and `b` to the function by *value*. So all you've passed to the function are 5 and 15. That you got these values from variables `a` and `b` does not matter to the function, since all it got were those values, not where you got them from.

The `a` and `b` variables inside the function are local variables that begin to exist while the function is executing and cease to exist when the function terminates. They are unrelated to the variables local to `main` that have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate what others have said, the variables you have defined in `main()` and `f()` are local. And `a` and `b` in `main()` are totally different and independent from similarly named ones in `f()`.

To get your desired result of `10`, you may use the following approach:

```
...
void f(int a, int& b){
    b=a+a;
}
```

(notice `&` before `b`)

What we did here is, we are passing 'b' as reference to `f()`. In this way, `f()` is allowed to modify its value and pass it back the new value to `main()`.

As an exercise, rename `a` and `b` in `f()` to `c` and `d`, and see the same results.